# How to close a process's stdout and stderr without `disown` or gdb?

Tags: linux, shell, portability, sh

I am porting some bash scripts to run on busybox. They use `disown`, which is not supported in ash, before killing some processes to prevent messages from that process appearing in the stdout/stderr. I'd like to preserve this functionality. Whether that means closing the stdout/sterr or redirecting to `/dev/null` after it's running.

How is it done?

Comment: Do you know about `nohup cmd &`, would that help? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, but rereading your post, I'm still not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you edit your posting to include psuedocode, expected inputs (if appropriate) and expected outputs in sequence. Does this set of scripts run as a daemon or from the crontab? Good luck.

Comment: One way to accomplish this would be to write a filter that passes output along until it receives a certain signal, then stops passing it. Then just pipe the other programs through that. More work than is ideal but I don't see another way to do it, given the constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify redirections for file descriptors once a process is running from outside that process. This means that you will have to do the redirection at the time the process is created by the shell. Whether that's redirecting to files or closing the fds like Ignacio showed is up to you.

And I am not sure why you think bash's disown built-in has any effect on file descriptors. Here's what the bash manual says:

```
   disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
        Without options, each jobspec  is  removed  from  the  table  of
        active  jobs.   If jobspec is not present, and neither -a nor -r
        is supplied, the shell's notion of the current job is used.   If
        the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed from the ta-
        ble, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if  the
        shell  receives a SIGHUP.  If no jobspec is present, and neither
        the -a nor the -r option is supplied, the current job  is  used.
        If no jobspec is supplied, the -a option means to remove or mark
        all jobs; the -r option without  a  jobspec  argument  restricts
        operation  to running jobs.  The return value is 0 unless a job-
        spec does not specify a valid job.
```

But maybe my understanding of what you are trying to achieve is incomplete.

Comment: This misunderstanding came from scripts that I'm porting. http://devresources.linuxfoundation.org/dev/hotplug/

They have a function that kills a pid, but before doing so calls disown. It has the side effect of not printing out 'process: killed' to the terminal. Busybox ash does not have disown, so I was looking for something similar. Turns out redirecting the output of kill does the job.

Answer (score 2):

`exec [n]>&-` will close FD `[n]`.

Comment: Hi, may I ask what is the `[n]`, is `1` of current shell or the stdin fd of process that want to disown? Can you give a full example ?